# How to set property type for property created within constructor - PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am using PHP.

As properties defined within the core of a class must be static, I have to create one property in the constructor to allow me to create it with a dynamic name.

Example

```
final class User extends Z
{

}

Abstract Class Z
{
    function __constructor()
    {
        $x = get_called_class() . 'Id';
        $this->$x = null;
    }
}
```

If we *var_dump()* *obj User* we would have

```
object(User)#1 (1) {
  ["UserId"]=>
  NULL
}
```

I want to set property A as a *protected* type.

How can I do this?
Or is there a better way to set the name of my dynamically named property?

Comment: I get: `object(A)#1 (0) { }` How do you create your obj?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can probably do is use magic getter/setter methods and an array of properties:

```
<?php

abstract class Z
{
    private $properties = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $x = get_called_class();
        $this->$x = null;
    }

    public function __set($prop, $val)
    {
        $this->properties[$prop] = $val;
    }

    public function __get($prop)
    {
        return $this->properties[$prop];
    }
}

class A extends Z
{

}

var_dump(new A());
```

Note that the property is private, child classes will have to go through the `__get` and `__set` methods.

You could also *restrict* dynamic properties to only be the called class name.

```
<?php

abstract class Z
{
    private $classprop;

    function __construct()
    {
        $x = get_called_class();
        $this->$x = true;
    }

    public function __set($prop, $val)
    {
        if ($prop !== get_called_class()) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Cannot Set Dynamic properties Other than Class Name');
        }

        $this->classprop = $val;
    }

    public function __get($prop)
    {
        if ($prop !== get_called_class()) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Cannot Get Dynamic properties Other than Class Name');
        }

        return $this->classprop;
    }
}

class A extends Z
{

}
```

I would encourage you to think pretty carefully about why you need dynamic properties like this.

Comment: I need it for only one property, and cannot think of a better way to do it.

Comment: Right, but `__get` and `__set` can't be used for only one property. Hence the array `$properties`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer would be don't - just use some generic base property, like `protected $Id;` and save the trouble.

If you really must have "dynamic" properties in class extensions, probably the simplest would be to declare the property in the extending class:

```
final class User extends Z {

    protected $UserId;

}
```

Then your code in `Z` will pick out this protected property. It's psudo-dynamic, since the property name is determined by the coder, and the script only "finds" it when the constructor is run, but if your property name is already determined by something fixed at compile-time, such as the class name, there's functionally no difference.

For truly dynamic property creation, you'd have to add in a runkit, an extension that allows you to programmatically change classes, methods, properties, and functions from within the script itself. A good one seems to be [this one by Demitry Zenovich](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit/). Unless you have some truly complex functions to carry out to justify the time working with it, though, it ain't going to make your life easier.